# Is the current user object saved even when an app is closed using Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, data-persistence

I am using Parse as the back end for my Android app and I noticed that even when I close my app completely, the current user is always the same user object from my Parse Cloud storage. Is this a feature of Parse or is the current user persistent because I am creating the user as an automatic user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parse sdk caches the user session when you signup or create a user automatically.

> Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk. You can treat this cache as a session, and automatically assume the user is logged in. You can clear the current user by logging them out:

Refer the docs [here](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users) :

Read the Current User section.